# Use Method of Indicators to Find E(Y)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to use (something like) the method of indicators to find E(Y) for the following pdf, which is a variation on the negative binomial:
\begin{equation}
{{y + r - 1}\choose{y - 1}}p^{r}(1 - p)^{y}
\end{equation} where $Y$ represents the number of failures, rather than the number of trials, until the $r^{th}$ success.  The solution to $E(Y)$ was given as $rp^{-1}(1 - p)$, but was obtained using

$$
 E(Y) = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty}yp(y)
$$

which involved lots of messy series manipulations. I'm wondering if the method of indicators might provide an easier solution.  Here's my attempt:

Let $Y$ be the number of failures until the $r^{th}$ success.  Next, let $Y_{1}$ be the number of failures until the first success, $Y_{2}$ the number of failures after the first success until the second success$\ldots Y_{r}$ the number of failures after the $r-1^{th}$ success until the $r^{th}$ success. Then $Y = (Y_{1} + Y_{2} + \cdots + Y_{r})$, and

$$
E(Y) = E(Y_{1}) + E(Y_{2}) + \cdots+ E(Y_{r})
$$ I note that $Y_{i}$ is not really an indicator -- it's more a way to decompose $Y$ into something that might be easier to work with.

If this makes sense, the question now is, what is $E(Y_{i})$?  Originally, I thought $Y_{i}$ had a geometric distribution, but that would imply $E(Y) = \frac{r}{q}$, which is false.  If anyone can point out the flaw in my design and figure out how to make this approach work, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decomposition seems right to me. $Y_i$ does follow a geometric distribution with parameter $p$ but the support is $\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$. The expectation of such variable is well-known to be $\frac{1-p}{p}$ (Wikipedia, [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)).

The expectation of a geometric random variable with parameter $p$ over $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$ is actually $\frac{1}{p}$.

Now we notice that
$$E[Y] = r\cdot\frac{1-p}{p}.$$

Comment: I didn't realize that the geometric distribution has a distinct support for number of failures until the first success!  Many thanks for pointing that out, and for the Wikipedia link.

Comment: @ScentlessApprentice It is a common trap. As the link states, there are two distributions commonly called "Geometric". That for the count of *failures before* first success, and that for the count of *trials until* first success.  It always helps to be *clear* on which one a text is discussing.

Comment: Well put. Thanks again!